# Unable to create pivot table

Tags: c#, excel, pivot

I'm trying to create an Excel Pivot table using C#. I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. While everything else works fine, when it comes to this line

```
Excel.PivotCache pivotCache = (Excel.PivotCache)wkb.PivotCaches()
```

there is no add option to add the data source but most online sources tell me that there is an add option. How can I add the data source?

Edit : Please be aware that Excel used here is actually using 
Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; The question still remains unanswered.

Comment: You are trying to cast a `PivorCaches` collection into a single `PivotCache` object. This makes no sense and shows no attempt to create and add an object. Have a look at the [PivotCaches.Create Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotcaches-create-method-excel).

Comment: Excel.PivotCache pivotCache = wkb.PivotCaches.Add();

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Add to get a single pivotcache object. Here is a sample:

```
void Main()
{
    Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
    var wb = xl.Workbooks.Add();
    var pc = wb.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal);

    pc.Connection = @"OLEDB;Provider=SQLNCLI11.0;server=.\SQLExpress2012;Database=Northwind;Trusted_connection=yes";
    pc.CommandType = XlCmdType.xlCmdSql;
    pc.CommandText = @"Select c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName, 
  o.orderId, o.orderDate, 
  e.FirstName+(' '+e.LastName) As Employee, 
  p.ProductName,
  od.UnitPrice, od.Quantity
  FROM  Customers c 
  INNER Join Orders o
  ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
  INNER Join Employees e 
  ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
  INNER Join [Order Details] od
  ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
  INNER Join products p 
  ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
  order By p.ProductName";

  var ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;
    pc.CreatePivotTable(ws.Range["A1"], "myPivot");
    var pt = (Excel.PivotTable)ws.PivotTables("myPivot");

    pt.AddFields(new string[] {"ProductName"}, new string[] {"Employee"});
    var pvf = (Excel.PivotField)pt.PivotFields("Quantity");
    pvf.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
    xl.Visible=true;
}
```

Comment: var pc = wb.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal); This is where I'm facing the issue. The .Add option doesn't appear after PivotCaches(). This is what I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: @KarthikeyanNatarajan, "doesn't appear" is NOT a problem, especially when you think of dynamic objects. Have you ever tried that and got an error?

Comment: @KarthikeyanNatarajan, That code is TESTED and WORKING. Probably you edited it to get the error.

Comment: My bad.. I'm used to coding with actual data types and had avoided using "variant" datatype like a plague all my life. So, yes you are right. The code that you had suggested is right. But one question though... Why the var data type..?? Why isn't there an exact datatype to handle this thing..??

Comment: @KarthikeyanNatarajan, var is the same thing as using the exact data type - it is NOT "variant" data type. It is just being lazy to type it myself instead of compiler doing that for me.

Comment: @KarthikeyanNatarajan, for which one are you asking? If you are asking for the line that reads "var pc = wb.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal);" then it is "Excel.PivotCache" and you could write that line as: "Excel.PivotCache pc = wb.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal);". Same thing. If you don't know the type, simply hover your mouse on to variable or var keyword to see the type as a tooltip.

Comment: That's the point. You see when I try and use "Excel.PivotCache pc = wb.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal);" Then the .Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal) doesn't pull up or gets resolved. It even gives me a runtime error.

Comment: @KarthikeyanNatarajan, it doesn't give me an error and works wonderfully well. Maybe you should use EPPlus instead.

Comment: Will give it a try.. Thanks for your time Cetin. Much Appreciated.